# Вылезает ошибка, при попытке расположить кнопки в нужном порядке

Tags: python

Вот моя ошибка:

```
File "D:\Shamil\Lib\site-packages\telebot\types.py", line 2583, in <listcomp>
    json_dict['inline_keyboard'] = [[button.to_dict() for button in row] for row in self.keyboard]
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Вот мой простой код:

```
import telebot
import webbrowser
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('#######')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def get_photo(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn1 = markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Перейти на сайт', url='https://youtube.com/shorts/qQ_QP99tTOI'))
    markup.row(btn1)
    btn2 = markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Удалить фото', callback_data='delete'))
    btn3 = markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Изменить текст', callback_data='edit'))
    markup.row(btn2, btn3)
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Красивое фото!', reply_markup=markup)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста, как решить это

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так должны кнопки добавляться:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def get_photo(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Перейти на сайт', url='https://youtube.com/shorts/qQ_QP99tTOI')
    markup.row(btn1)
    btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Удалить фото', callback_data='delete')
    btn3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Изменить текст', callback_data='edit')
    markup.row(btn2, btn3)
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Красивое фото!', reply_markup=markup)
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, работает!!!!!